# How do I prevent figure pages from interrupting passages?

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I've written a text with some page-size figures in it. The problem is: The figure pages are interrupting sentences and paragraphs. The figures are supposed to be looked at for some time, so I'd like to have any paragraphs completed before the figure page.

While \widowpenalty10000 and \clubpenalty10000 prevent the pages from starting or ending with a single word of another paragraph, they still don't solve my problem of the figure interrupting a paragraph.

Positioning the figure manually is something I'd like to avoid. The surrounding pages are supposed to be as full as possible without interrupting a paragraph.

The goal is that Latex realises that a paragraph is being interrupted and either moves the start of that paragraph to the first page after the float, squeezes the rest of that paragraph to the page before the float or finds a better positon for the float.

Minimal problem example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{imagenotfound.jpg}
\end{figure}

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. % The next page starts with only the last word of this passage. I don't want that. Please move the whole passage to the next page.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo

\end{document}
```

Comment: `[Hp]` is a syntax error, so definitely avoid that:-) (`H` if used has to be on its own)

Comment: Realised that a second ago, too. Also it doesn't do what I had in mind. Amended the question.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the simplest fix here is to add `\looseness=-1` as in:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{imagenotfound.jpg}
\end{figure}

    \looseness=-1
    Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
 labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
 accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
 sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
 amet, consetetur
 sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
 dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. % The next page starts with only the last word of this passage. I don't want that. Please move the whole passage to the next page.
```

which makes that paragraph be compressed into one line less so avoiding the lone word.

Comment: But where do I add \looseness=-1? To which passage? Is there a way to find out which passage will be the interrupted one?

Comment: @Drache198 not easily (other than doing as I did and looking at the output and adding a manual fix): in tex line and page breaking are very much separated. In general how do you expect this to work? latex would need some algorithm to implement, by "passsage" you seem to mean paragraph, and you want to allow page-breaking mid-paragraph but only allow floats to be inserted on pages that happen to break between paragraphs? That seems hard to implement.

Comment: The idea was that Latex realises: "Hey, this float is interrupting a paragraph" and then either moves the start of that paragraph to the first page after the float or squeezes the rest of it to the page before the float.

Comment: @Drache198 you are going to have to do some "final corrections" by hand to achieve that.

Comment: @JohnKormylo you could fiddle with `\interlinepenalty` and look at `\outputpenalty` but normally latex doesn't. I don't think `\everypar` would help much as typically the next paragraph (and so `\everypar`) has already been set before tex decided to back up and start splitting pages